# bash variable extension forward slash, percentage sign meaning

Tags: bash

I saw following lines at a bash script, don't understand why is it look like that.

```
KO_PATH=/lib/modules
insmod ${KO_PATH/%\//}/test.ko
```

why not direct write insmod /lib/modules/test.ko?

Comment: To give an opinion on your second question: you may have heard of the concept of "Magic Numbers." The idea we don't hardcode numbers in our code for readability and in case they change. When scripting, this same concept extends to strings too. I like to call doing something like `insmod /lib/modules/test.ko` making a "magic string." It's better to have a variable for a string for readability and in case you plan to use it elsewhere in the code.

Comment: It trims the final `'/'` from `KO_PATH` so there is never a double directory separator. It uses the awkward bash-only substitution form where it could be POSIX compliant with `${KO_PATH%/}`

Comment: _why not direct write_ : Well, think about why you are (hopefully) using named constants in your  programs, instead of writing the value explicitly wherever it is needed....

Answer (score 0):

The "forward slash, percentage sign" functionality is string manipulation. This behaviour is [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

It is put a little more succinctly in [the ABS](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
${string/substring/replacement}

    Replace first match of $substring with $replacement.
```

It looks like it's to remove any trailing slashes from `KO_PATH` so that doing `KO_PATH="/lib/modules/"` doesn't result in a path like `/lib/modules//test.ko`

```bash
[user@host]$ KO_PATH=/lib/modules/
[user@host]$ echo ${KO_PATH/%\//}/test.ko
/lib/modules/test.ko
[user@host]$ echo ${KO_PATH}/test.ko
/lib/modules//test.ko
```

In the case of your example it is effectively doing nothing though:

```bash
[user@host]$ KO_PATH=/lib/modules
[user@host]$ echo ${KO_PATH/%\//}/test.ko
/lib/modules/test.ko
```